# Why do I get null cannot be cast to non-null type net.corda.core.identity.Party error with Oraclize?

Tags: kotlin, corda

I've been trying to implement Oraclize into my CorDapp and the flow I have created works perfectly but when I try to add an Oraclize query I received the error: null cannot be cast to non-null type net.corda.core.identity.Party. This is the code in question.

```
        val current = LocalDateTime.now().toString()
        val airplaneStatus = subFlow(OraclizeQueryAwaitFlow(
            datasource = "URL",
            query = "json(https://api.flightstats.com/flex/flightstatus/rest/v2/json/flight/status/" + flight.subSequence(0,2) + "/" + flight.subSequence(2, flight.length) + "/arr/" +
            current.subSequence(0,4) + "/" + current.subSequence(5,7) + "/" + current.subSequence(8,10) + "?appId=******&appKey=***********&utc=false).flightStatuses.status",
            proofType = ProofType.TLSNOTARY,
            delay = 1
        ))
```

A flight is a simple Flight ID such as AC345 or WS9405. The entire flow is here: https://pastebin.com/7uvPnjEf

**UPDATE:** I have added the `delay` parameter but the error persists (tried 0 and 1). I have also verified that `ProofType.TLSNOTARY` is non-null.

Thanks in advance!

Log Error Report:

```
[WARN ] 2018-07-10T16:08:00,619Z [Node thread-1] flow.[a0362ed5-74b5- 
4519-a80e-4adda70adca7].run - Terminated by unexpected exception {}
kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type net.corda.core.identity.Party
at it.oraclize.cordapi.flows.OraclizeQueryAwaitFlow.call(OraclizeQueryAwaitFlow.kt:36) ~[InsureFlight-0.1.jar:?]
at it.oraclize.cordapi.flows.OraclizeQueryAwaitFlow.call(OraclizeQueryAwaitFlow.kt:18) ~[InsureFlight-0.1.jar:?]
at net.corda.core.flows.FlowLogic.subFlow(FlowLogic.kt:290) ~[corda-core-3.1-corda.jar:?]
at com.insureflight.flows.IssuePolicy$Initiator.call(IssuePolicy.kt:76) ~[cordapp-0.1.jar:?]
at com.insureflight.flows.IssuePolicy$Initiator.call(IssuePolicy.kt:37) ~[cordapp-0.1.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:96) [corda-node-3.1-corda.jar:?]
at net.corda.node.services.statemachine.FlowStateMachineImpl.run(FlowStateMachineImpl.kt:44) [corda-node-3.1-corda.jar:?]
at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.run1(Fiber.java:1092) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.Fiber.exec(Fiber.java:788) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.doExec(RunnableFiberTask.java:100) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
at co.paralleluniverse.fibers.RunnableFiberTask.run(RunnableFiberTask.java:91) [quasar-core-0.7.9-jdk8.jar:0.7.9]
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_172]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_172]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [?:1.8.0_172]
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [?:1.8.0_172]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_172]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_172]
at net.corda.node.utilities.AffinityExecutor$ServiceAffinityExecutor$1$thread$1.run(AffinityExecutor.kt:62) [corda-node-3.1-corda.jar:?]
```

Comment: Add log error here, pls!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seing the repository from library on github and your log error (line 36 from OraclizeQueryAwaitFlow.kt, see [here](https://github.com/oraclize/corda-api/blob/f20b47ae102c999b2e18552d67ab1d584eba3b21/src/main/kotlin/it/oraclize/cordapi/flows/OraclizeQueryAwaitFlow.kt)), I am presume that problem occurre because

- The call `serviceHub.identityService.wellKnownPartyFromX500Name(OraclizeUtils.getNodeName())` return null
- The null value want be casted for `Party`, but it is no possible, throwing an `TypeCastException`

#### My sugestions

**1.** (Recomended) Open an issue on this repository asking for this error solution and wait the response from developers, or

**2.** Fork this repository and you verify this cast attempt and use your repository forked

Answer (score 0):

You forgot of pass the 4th parameter, the parameter `delay`

```
OraclizeQueryAwaitFlow(val datasource: String,
                             val query: Any,
                             val proofType: Int = 0,
                             val delay: Int = 0) //here <------
```

**Why?**

This parameter is no-null (it not have an elvis (`?`) operator) and need be atribuited

Comment: I've passed delay and it still shows the same error. I've tried delay at 0 and delay at 1. val current = LocalDateTime.now().toString()
            val airplaneStatus = subFlow(OraclizeQueryAwaitFlow(
                datasource = "URL",
                query = foo,
                proofType = ProofType.TLSNOTARY,
                delay = 1
            ))

Comment: Verify if `ProofType.TLSNOTARY` is null

Comment: I have verified that proofType is non-null and the error persists

Answer (score 0):

Did you load the Cordapp on the public testnet? If not, that could be the problem because the `identityService` couldn't reach our public node. We are currently working on a tool for testing on private networks, but in the meantime, you should load your cordapp on a node connected to the public testnet.

Comment: I'll give that a try and let you know.

Comment: Looking at https://docs.corda.net/changelog.html, Corda's most recent comment on the testnest is "Note that currently there is no public Corda testnet, so we are not currently running a permissioning service". How would I then connect to the public testnet?

Comment: Maybe they forgot to put it in the changelog, but standing from here https://docs.corda.net/releases/release-V2.0/permissioning.html# there should be a public testnet from `release-V2.0`. Which version of corda are you using?

Comment: Currently using V3.1

Comment: Currently we are supporting V2.0 on the public testnet. An API supporting corda V3.1 will be released in the next few days, in the meantime could you please share with us your `compatibilityZoneURL` of your compatibility zone, so we can join your network? Feel free to reach us on our public channel on [gitter](https://gitter.im/oraclize/corda-api?utm_source=badge&utm_medium=badge&utm_campaign=pr-badge&utm_content=badge)